# Foreign address line not long enough in Form 1040NR

Tags: united-states, irs

I am filling out Form 1040NR using a long India address. However, the 'Home address' line is not long enough. Any ideas on how I can provide a longer address? Can I write 3 lines using my pen in small fonts instead of filling out using the pdf filler utility.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It my get cut off in their computer anyway. The IRS has a 35-chars limit for street address for 1040, I'm not sure if it also applies to 1040NR